# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. with input - react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i have this:

```
{array.map((item) => (
                <>
                    <input
                        key={item.id}
                        type="checkbox"
                    />
                    <h3>{item.value}</h3>
                </>
            ))}
```

and in the website i see the warning: "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." but i put the "key" attribute.
does anyone know why?

Comment: The `key={item.id}` would have to be on the `<>` element, not the `<input>` element (if that's even possible; my react is rusty)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fragment element (`<></>`) is the top-level child element here, and it needs a `key` prop.  The short syntax being used doesn't support adding an attribute, but the longer syntax does:

```
<React.Fragment key={item.id}>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <h3>{item.value}</h3>
</React.Fragment>
```